# inserir arquvo CSS no FPDF

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte **código**:

```
$estiloSite = file_get_contents('http://localhost/wesleyanagceu.com.br/_scripts/_css/style.css');
$estiloAdmin = file_get_contents('http://localhost/wesleyanagceu.com.br/_scripts/_css/admin.css');

require_once "_classes/_util/_PDF/PDF.php";

$html = $_POST["htmlPDF"];

$pdf = new PDF;
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->WriteHTML( $estiloSite, "_classes/_util/_PDF::HEADER_CSS");
$pdf->WriteHTML( $estiloAdmin, "_classes/_util/_PDF::HEADER_CSS");
$pdf->WriteHTML( utf8_decode ( $html ) );
$pdf->Output("relatorio.pdf","D");
```

Não estou achando na documentação do **FPDF** como se faz isso que no **mPDF** é dessa forma:

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
```

Da forma acima funciona no **mPFD**.

Como seria no **FPDF** sabendo que serviu de **base** para **criação** do **mPF**?

Answer (score 3):

Até onde consegui verificar o FPDF não tem essa função, ele não lida muito bem com CSS, tem alguns plugins que lidam com style inline, mas não é muita coisa. Essa função é uma das coisas que o [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io) adicionou. Recomendo você usar ele ou o [HTML2PDF](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf).

Comment: O FPDF são apenas 2 arquivos, já o mPDF... Por isso estou dando preferência ao PPDF. Mas se não houver outro jeito...